# How to access promise passed back through a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express, promise

I am new to promises on javascript, so thanks for any help. My code attempts to access the database from firebase and pass a list in a function from main_page.js to index.js. I am getting back my result in a promise and I am having difficulty accessing the value within.

**main_page.js: UniqueCourse Function to retrieve course from firebase. Returns a list of courses**

```
    // Get Unique Course ID
    function UniqueCourse(t_id){
      var courseArray = []
      return Promise.resolve(
        firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value',

        function(snapshot) {
          details = snapshot.val()
          //console.log(snapshot.val());

         for (var key in details) {
            if (details.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              //console.log(key + " , " + details[key].username + "\n");
              if (details[key].username == t_id){
                console.log("Details of Array " + details[key].courses.split(','));
                courseArray = details[key].courses.split(',');
                return courseArray
              }
            }
          }
        })
      ).then(function(value){
        return value;
      })
    }
```

**main_page.js: Export UniqueCourse Function to be used outside**

```
    module.exports.UniqueCourse = (t_id) => {
        return UniqueCourse(t_id)
    }
```

**index.js: Take list passed from UniqueCourse function in main_page.js**

```
    Promise.resolve(main_page.UniqueCourse(req.body.username)).then(function(value){
      console.log(value);
     })
```

---

The console.log(value) from index.js should contain the list of courses from UniqueCourse(t_id). However, what I am getting is a promise object shown on console.log(value). I have difficulty accessing the list from the promise object.

**Console Output**

```
    Details of Array CZ4047,CZ3003

    DataSnapshot {
      node_:
       ChildrenNode {
         children_:
          SortedMap { comparator_: [Function: NAME_COMPARATOR], root_: [LLRBNode] },
         priorityNode_:
          ChildrenNode {
            children_: [SortedMap],
            priorityNode_: null,
            indexMap_: [IndexMap],
            lazyHash_: '' },
         indexMap_: IndexMap { indexes_: [Object], indexSet_: [Object] },
         lazyHash_: null },
      ref_:
       Reference {
         repo:
          Repo {
            repoInfo_: [RepoInfo],
            app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
            dataUpdateCount: 2,
            statsListener_: null,
            eventQueue_: [EventQueue],
            nextWriteId_: 1,
            interceptServerDataCallback_: null,
            onDisconnect_: [SparseSnapshotTree],
            persistentConnection_: [PersistentConnection],
            stats_: [StatsCollection],
            server_: [PersistentConnection],
            statsReporter_: [StatsReporter],
            transactionQueueTree_: [Tree],
            infoData_: [SnapshotHolder],
            infoSyncTree_: [SyncTree],
            serverSyncTree_: [SyncTree],
            __database: [Database] },
         path: Path { pieces_: [Array], pieceNum_: 0 },
         queryParams_:
          QueryParams {
            limitSet_: false,
            startSet_: false,
            startNameSet_: false,
            endSet_: false,
            endNameSet_: false,
            limit_: 0,
            viewFrom_: '',
            indexStartValue_: null,
            indexStartName_: '',
            indexEndValue_: null,
            indexEndName_: '',
            index_: PriorityIndex {} },
         orderByCalled_: false },
      index_: PriorityIndex {} }
```

**Expected Console Output**

```
    Details of Array CZ4047,CZ3003

    [CZ4047,CZ3003]
```

---

Comment: Don't put a "solved" section in your answer. That is not how Stack Overflow works. The answer to a question should be in the answers section. If you have an answer yourself that is not an answer already posted, then post one yourself. That is acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is the reason that you `Promise.resolve(anotherPromise)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

The problem is solved by moving the logic to the back of the promise on the firebase data snapshot.

```
    // Get Unique Course ID
    function UniqueCourse(t_id){
      var courseArray = []
      return Promise.resolve(
        firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value',function(snapshot) {})
        ).then(function(snapshot){

        details = snapshot.val();
        //console.log(snapshot.val());

        for (var key in details) {
          if (details.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //console.log(key + " , " + details[key].username + "\n");
            if (details[key].username == t_id){
              console.log("Details of Array " + details[key].courses.split(','));
              courseArray = details[key].courses.split(',');
            }
          }
        }
        return courseArray;
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once), the `once` method returns a `Promise<DataSnapshot>`

```js
return Promise.resolve(
    firebase.database().ref("xxx").once(function () { /* ..logic.. */ })
).then(function (value) { // this is 'DataSnapshot'
    return value;
})
```

You get the value from DataSnapshot and return as below

```js
return Promise.resolve(
    firebase.database().ref("xxx").once(function () { /* ..logic.. */ })
).then(function (snapshot) {
    return snapshot.val(); // I believe this is syntax. please check the docs
})
```

Comment: @ChristopherTan If you find this helpful, please upvote

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with promises you can avoid the `.then` loop using `async/await`. For using async/await use babel to transpile the code to the supported version by your Node version.

```
// Get Unique Course ID
    function sync UniqueCourse(t_id){
      var courseArray = []
      const snapshot = await firebase.database().ref('/users').once('value')
      const details = snapshot.val();
      for (var key in details) {
          if (details.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //console.log(key + " , " + details[key].username + "\n");
            if (details[key].username == t_id){
              console.log("Details of Array " + details[key].courses.split(','));
              courseArray = details[key].courses.split(',');
            }
          }
        }
      return courseArray
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with firebase, but I think you could rewrite your query to

```
function UniqueCourse(t_id) {
    return firebase.database()
        .ref('/users')
        .orderByChild('username').equalTo(t_id)
        .child('courses')
        .once('value')
        .then(snapshot => snapshot.exists() ? 
            snapshot.val()[0].split(",") : 
            []
         );
}
```

Therefore you do not download all your users, just to get a string on one of them. Instead you only download the actual data you want; the courses for the users that match the filter.